# Can we reduce time complexity of the maximum winner problem?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Two teams (*A* and *B*) are competing each other. Each team has the same number of players. Every team member, of both teams, has some power associated with them. *A* player can win only when their power is strictly greater than the opponent's power. A player from team *A* is paired with a player in team *B*, following the way the players are arranged in both teams. We can arrange the players in both teams the way we want. Arrange the teams in such a way that team *A* has more winners than losers.

***Input Format:***
The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, *T*

The first line of each test case consists of the number of members each team can have, *N*.

The second line of each test case consists of *N* space-separated integers representing the power of team *A* members.

The third line of each test case consists of *N* space-separated integers representing the power of opponent (*B*) team members.

***Constraints:***

- 1 <= T <=100000
- 1 <= N <=100000
- 0 <= Power of team member <= LLONG_MAX

***Output Format:***
For each test case, print the maximum number of winners Team *A* can win if they go to fight in an optimal manner.

***Explanation:***
***Input:***

Team A: 20, 30, 50
Team B: 60, 40, 25

In the above arrangement, team *A* has only one winner: the last player would win (50 > 25).

If we arrange the teams like:

Team A: 20, 50, 30
Team B: 60, 40, 25

Then team *A* has 2 winners. Players 2 and 3, with power 50 > 40 and 30 > 25 would win.

***Another test case:***

```
1
10
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
```

I can solve this problem by first sorting both arrays in non-decreasing order. Then start from the last index of the array to first index of the array. I set two pointers: `i` to the end of `A` and `j` to the end of `B`. Then decrement `i` only when `A[i]>B[j]` and increment count.

Decrement j every time.

```cpp
// A: Power of team member A
// B: Power of team member B
// n: size of arrays
while(t--){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int A[n],B[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>A[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>B[i];
    }

    sort(A,A+n);
    sort(B,B+n);

    // operation
    int count=0;
    int j=n-1;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0&&j>=0;){
        if(A[i]>B[j]){
            count++;
            i--;
        }
        j--;
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
}
```

This whole operation takes *O(nlog(n))* if we use merge sort. Can we reduce the time complexity?

Comment: Given in question, it can be `LLONG_MAX`

Comment: In my opinion you can't avoid sorting the teams. Therefore O(n  logn) at best, as counting sort is not an option here

Comment: @Damien - You are right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it is a greedy algorithm. We are picking the optimal choice every time. You are doing right. We need to sort both arrays. If we use merge sort then time complexity would be `O(nlog(n))`. 
One statement is very popular in algorithm design is `can I do batter?`. Apply different approaches then figure out the relation between those approaches. Try to minimize time complexity if you have extra time. Because your algorithm is optimized enough.

Comment: I think you meant O(n log n), not O(log n) for merge sort time complexity.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Typing mistake!. I am changing this.